# PLONK: Rationale Behind Specific Polynomial Evaluations in Round 4

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

In round 4, protocol evaluates `a(zeta), b(zeta), c(zeta), Sσ1(zeta), Sσ2(zeta)`. I know linearisation trick in round 5 implies the identity of other terms. Can we evaluate other term e.g. `Sσ1(zeta), Sσ3(zeta)` instead? Is there any consideration behind these selected terms in paper?

ref:

1. PLONK paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/953.pdf
2. https://hackmd.io/@aztec-network/ByiUK_Plt